# A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to implement a check that if user displayName is null in firebase. It should navigate to a form where he has to enter his name. Currently displayName in firebase is null by default. But i'm getting an error.

A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.

'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':

Failed assertion: line 360 pos 10: 'data != null'

```
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 30),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("Welcome !"),
          // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
          Text(snapshot.data.documents
                      .elementAt(index)['displayName']) !=
                  null
              ? Text(snapshot.data.documents
                  .elementAt(index)['displayName'])
              : Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/UserDetail'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 30),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text("Welcome !"),
          // ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks
          snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'] !=
                  null
              ? Text(snapshot.data.documents
                  .elementAt(index)['displayName'])
              : Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/UserDetail'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

The `Text` widget won't give you `null`. Only the data that you give can be `null`

Comment: It worked but getting this now. The following assertion was thrown building:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the

Comment: Where are you calling setState? Show your entire code

Answer (score 0):

#### You're missing a lot. Let's try to fix that!

1. It is a bad idea to ignore possible errors.
2. Never write `// ignore: unrelated_type_equality_checks`
3. What is your code trying to do? We need to know what you need.

#### What is wrong with what you wrote?

1. `// ignore:`  forces the linter to ignore a specific kind of problem. You have ignored `unrelated_type_equality_checks` which means you don't think it is an error to compare two different data-types. This is not good. `2` and `"someString"` are different data-types. When you compare them: `2 == "someString"` it will never evaluate to `true`. It will always be `false`.
2. **The actual comparison you wrote is always true.**

```js
              Text(snapshot.data.documents
                      .elementAt(index)['displayName']) !=
                  null
              ? Text(snapshot.data.documents
                  .elementAt(index)['displayName'])
              : Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/UserDetail')
```

Here's that comparison on just one line:

```js
Text(snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName']) != null
```

Let's simplify this to show what is wrong. See why the comparison is always true?

```js
Text('displayName') != null // always true
```

You probably meant to write: (*I've only removed Text() from the comparison you wrote.*)

```js
              snapshot.data.documents
                      .elementAt(index)['displayName'] !=
                  null
              ? Text(snapshot.data.documents
                  .elementAt(index)['displayName'])
              : Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/UserDetail')
```

But this code still doesn't make sense! If the document's display name was not null, a `Text` widget is the result of the comparison. If the display name **was null**, we call `Navigator.pushNamed` which is not a function that returns a `Widget`. We need both parts of the ternary operator to return a `Widget`, and only the `Text()` part returns a `Widget`. The call to `Navigator.pushNamed` does not return a `Widget`, which is an error.

**Here is how you can fix that type mismatch:**

```js
              snapshot.data.documents
                      .elementAt(index)['displayName'] !=
                  null
              ? Text(snapshot.data.documents
                  .elementAt(index)['displayName'])
              : Text("Something went wrong!")
```

But there's another problem after we fix that type mismatch in the ternary operator. We are repeating ourselves! `snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName']` is written twice! **Don't repeat yourself**

```js
              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              name != null
                  ? Text(name)
                  : Text("Something went wrong!")
```

See how we get a `Text` `Widget` no matter what? We can shorten it!

```js
              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              Text(name != null ? name : "Something went wrong!")
```

This null-check is so common that Dart gives an operator `??` to do it.

```js
              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              Text(name ?? "Something went wrong!")
```

But there are still bugs in this code.

I have to assume that `snapshot` has the data-type `AsyncSnapshot` because your example wasn't complete. `AsyncSnapshot` might be an error, and it might be data. You have to check before you use the data!

```js
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("Oops!");

              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              Text(name ?? "Something went wrong!")
```

It's not an error to be waiting for the document to arrive. That means we need to check if the `AsyncSnapshot` has data yet!

```js
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("Oops!");
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("No data yet!");

              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              Text(name ?? "Something went wrong!")
```

Great! Now we're sure there is data in the snapshot! But what if that data is an empty list?

```js
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("Oops!");
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("No data yet!");
              if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) return Text("No documents!");

              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              Text(name ?? "Something went wrong!")
```

But what if we get just one document in the list of documents, and `index` is `5`? That would be a `RangeError`. What if `displayName` is not in the document? That would be a `KeyError`.

If you are confident that your `index` isn't going to be too big, and that all of your documents have a `displayName`, feel free to ignore the possible errors.

#### Here is what we get when we fix all of the misunderstandings.

```js
              if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("Oops!");
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text("No data yet!");
              if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty) return Text("No documents!");

              var name = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(index)['displayName'];
              
              return Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50, left: 30),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text("Welcome !"),
                        Text(name ?? "Something went wrong!")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
```